# Is there any way to avoid pro*c precompiler?

Tags: openssl, proc, oracle-pro-c, precompiler, tuxedo

I’ve been trying to use openSSL on Oracle tuxedo but its pro-c compiler keep making error.
People says pro*c pre-compiler can’t handle code in c99 syntax.

I’d like to know how my code can avoid pre-compiler.

According to openssl github issue (https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/9778)

“ wrap your code with defines and add it to the proc call. That code path will be disabled for the Oracle preprocessor”

I have no idea how to do that.
I tried like this but it doesn’t work.
#ifndef **precomp_test**
#define **precomp_test**
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#endif

All I did is only including ssl.h so far.
Can anybody tell me how to avoid precompiler?

Answer (score 0):

You should look at PRO*C precompiler option `PARSE={FULL | PARTIAL | NONE}`. Unless you have a legacy codebase I suggest using `PARSE=NONE` which means the precompiler will not try to parse the whole C (or C++) code and instead look only at blocks and lines with `EXEC SQL` directives.